# I have issue with qrcode.react and react-to-print lib

Tags: reactjs

I try to use QRCode render in table.
When I got print preview,
they show QRCode only first page of the print preview.
I want to get QRCode to show all on the thead of table.

```
class TableToPrint extends Component {
render() {
const { refTransNo, transNo, rows } = this.props;
const style = { borderBottom: "none", padding: "4px 8px" };

return (
  <div className="table" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <table
      style={{
        tableLayout: "fixed",
        width: "100%",
        wordBreak: "break-all",
      }}
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colSpan="2" width="45%" style={{ ...style }}>
            <h2 className="left">Left</h2>
            <br />
            <h2 className="left">Right: {refTransNo}</h2>
          </th>
          <th colSpan="4" width="55%" style={{ ...style }}>
            <strong style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }}>{transNo}</strong>
            <div
              style={{
                marginBottom: !transNo ? "0px" : "7px",
              }}
            >
              {transNo && <QRCode value={transNo} size={60} level={"H"} />}
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <thead>
        <tr className="font-head">
          <th width="5%">1</th>
          <th width="35%">2</th>

          <th width="14%">3</th>
          <th width="18%">4</th>
          <th width="14%">5</th>
          <th width="14%">6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <RowsTable {...{ rows }} />
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

```
class PrintPreview extends Component {
render() {
const { dataToPrint } = this.props;

return (<><TableToPrint { //pass many props here}/></>)
```

...

```
function Print({...props}) {
const printRef = useRef();
  <ReactToPrint
    onBeforeGetContent={onBeforeGetContent}
    onAfterPrint={onAfterPrint}
    trigger={() => <a>{trigger}</a>}
    content={() => printRef.current}
  />

  {isPrint && (
    <PrintPreview 
      ref={printRef}
      {...{
        data,
        dataToPrint,
        accessLog,
      }}
    />
  )}
</>
}
```

I use qrcode.react version 1
, react version 16
, react-to-print version 2.

Note:

- I want to use current version.
- I use class component for PrintPreview and other inside this
  component because I get error react-to-print can use with only class.